# JSDoc Toolkit - How to specify @param and @property on same line

Tags: javascript, documentation, documentation-generation, jsdoc

Is there a way to avoid having to type two seperate lines for @property and @param if, as in the example, on the constructor the parameters and properties are identically named.

```
/**
 * Class for representing a point in 2D space.
 * @property {number} x The x coordinate of this point.
 * @property {number} y The y coordinate of this point.
 * @constructor
 * @param {number} x The x coordinate of this point.
 * @param {number} y The y coordinate of this point.
 * @return {Point} A new Point
 */
Point = function (x, y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not. It is impossible, because the arguments of the function and properties of an object - these are different variables, they can not be both function parameters and object properties.
Moreover, such documentation would only confuse the developer, but does not help to understand the API.

I would advise you not to use the @properties in this piece of documentation, but use @type:

```
/**
 * Class for representing a point in 2D space.
 * @constructor
 * @param {number} x The x coordinate of this point.
 * @param {number} y The y coordinate of this point.
 * @return {Point} A new Point
 */
Point = function (x, y)
{
    /**
     * The x coordinate.
     * @type number
     */
    this.x = x;

    /**
     * The y coordinate.
     * @type number
     */
    this.y = y;
}
```

But in fact such detailed documentation is useless. What are we talking in code `Point.x = x` is clear to any schoolchild.

Comment: My suggestion is that you only declare jsdoc properties from the constructor as you have (even if it's only going to get assigned later. Avoid creating them from random functions in a class.